# How to use a 32 bit running SSIS DataSource (like Run64bitRuntime=false) in an 64 bit SSRS to connect to Access DB

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ms-access-2010

I have a SSRS (2008 R2 64 bits) report where i want to expose data from an Access (Office 2010 32 bits) DB, both in an 64bit OS.

After searching, it seemed the proposed solution would be to use a SSIS package as a middle man.

After implementing everything in BIDS, it worked, but not when I deployed in SSRS (error in the datasource: "The package failed to validate.").

To be sure the package was ok, I deployed it, and ran using DTEXEC in the command line, result:

```
Using the 32bit DTEXEC - it worked
Using the default 64bit DTEXEC - the same error appeared
```

That's how I conclude the problem is in the "bits"...

Supposedly, since in SSRS, the connection string of the SSIS extension is basically invoking DTEXEC, one should be able to use the "/X86 switch to enable the 32 bit runtime mode" stated [here](http://visakhm.blogspot.pt/2011/11/excel-2010-export-import-issue-in-64.html) (in the end), but it didn't work...

So, now what, I ask...any ideas...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But if you look at the [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation it clearly calls out the the /x86 option is only valid for SQL Agent usage and is ignored by the command line client. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943765/why-does-my-odbc-connection-fail-when-running-an-ssis-load-in-visual-studio-but/13960063#13960063

Comment: That said, I don't understand your process. An SSRS report needs data from Access and SSIS is pushing data somehow but I don't understand how the SSIS package which must run in 32 bit mode has any impact on the reports which are a server "thing" and are running in 64 bit mode. Could you help clarify your question? Use the edit button if you could and not comments to do so

Answer (score 0):

If you want 32bit, you can execute `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe'` instead of `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe'`.