# Ways to automate SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that needs to be run daily. It needs excel to execute the active tasks in the package. I cannot install excel in the SQL server that I have, so I cannot create a SQL job to run the SSIS package.
Are there other options to automate SSIS packages?

Comment: dtexec and a scheduled task.

Comment: To restate: You have an SSIS package that depends on an installation of MS Office (Excel) to function properly. Your question is: how do I get this to run without installing Office on the database server?

Comment: @bilinkc Yes, Is that possible?

Comment: Not without reworking your package to not use the Excel object model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364449/custom-logging-in-active-task-ssis#comment60588310_36364793

Comment: I need to use the object model to format the excel file, Is there a different approach that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install Excel on the SQL Server in order to use Excel as a source or destination.
You do, however, need to box clever.

I'd recommend Project Deployment to SSISDB.
Then a use SQL Agent to schedule. Within the SQL Agent Job Step --> Configuration --> Advanced and click on 32-Bit runtime.

[image]

Comment: I had tried this,but when I run the job i get the exception in Active Task" Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))" at the code line Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application(); When I installed excel in the dev server and checked it started to work. But I cannot do that in my production server, that is why I am looking for other options.

Comment: FYI, I need to format the excel and I do that in Active task.