# The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager PostgreSQL30.app_user failed with error code 0xC0014009

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, odbc, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a SSIS package which I've been developing inside Visual Studio Community 2019 (VS). I have installed Integration Services to develop the SSIS package.

The task of the package is pretty simple, connect to a PostgreSQL datasource via an ODBC connection and then perform a lookup to identify new and updated fields and pass these into a MS SQL database via an OLE DB connection. When I run this package from both VS and via cmdp using dtexec.exe it runs successfully without any error (yay).

I run into a problem when I try to *execute* this package after deploying it from VS using the Deploy Package Wizard to SSISDB on MS SQL Server(2016). **The errors can be found in the image below**. Please note that I have selected *Target Server Version SQL Server 2016* so there should be no compatibility issues between the package and server.

[image]

I have read that there may be a compatibility issue between 64 & 32-bit. However, I have no idea how to configure this from within SSISDB. I did however, attempt to execute the package with run64bitruntime set to "false" (done inside vs) and "true" with no change in result. my version of SSMS 2016 is running 64-bit.

I should also add that I'm connecting remotely to SSMS 2016 to run the package from SSISDB, remote connections is set to true for this server.

Please let me know if I can supply further details to help debug this. Thank you.

Comment: The 0xC0014009 error sounds a lot like: [Why does my ODBC connection fail when running an SSIS load in Visual Studio but not when running the same package using Execute Package Utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943765/why-does-my-odbc-connection-fail-when-running-an-ssis-load-in-visual-studio-but)

Comment: Thanks but I have read this article and tested modifying the setting already. SSMS 2016 is running 64bit and I've tested Run64BitRuntime both enabled and disabled.